# Failed motor mount on 2007 Jetta Wolfsburg edition

Tags: fuel-system, motor-mounts

7 months ago a motor mount failed on my 2007 VW Jetta Wolfsburg edition. Since then it has sat 7 months. It was running fine the last time it was started.

1. Should I replace all the motor mounts, or just the one that failed?
2. Should I flush the fuel system since the car has sat for a long time?

Comment: Welcome to the site @EmanuelPittman! Unfortunately your question is hard to understand, what is the problem with your car? What are the symptoms, and what have you done to resolve them?

Comment: One of the motor mounts broke so I stopped driving it. I am now ready to repair it bit know i needs to clean The fuel system before trying to start it again. Want to know the best way to clean the fuel system

Comment: What does a motor mount breaking have to do with a fuel system clean?

Comment: It's been sitting for more than 7 months without being started

Comment: I know I need to change the dog bone now but wanted to know if everyone thought I should do all of them while doing this one. (Motor mount)

Comment: @EmanuelPittman So what? "Sitting idle for 7 months" is not a reason to clean the fuel system, unless you *know* you did something that would let dirt get into it.

Comment: So you're asking 2 things: 1) how to clean the fuel system and 2) should you replace all the motor mounts. I suggest you edit to make that clear.

Comment: I  just wanted to make sure that I don't need to flush the system due to the car sitting with fuel in it . The mount question is... Should I just replace the one or replace them all

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear. I'm kind of new to this

Comment: I've edited your question, please let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Is it a Diesel or Gasoline?

Answer (score 1):

There is usually no need to flush the fuel system if a car's been sitting for 7-8 months, the fuel may have degraded some but you should be all right. Next time if you know a car is going to be sitting that long put fuel stabilizer in the tank. If you think the fuel may have significant contamination for some reason, like the cap was left off then the procedure would be to drain the tank and fill it with fresh fuel, and replace the fuel filter. Your injectors haven't worked in awhile, so maybe running a system cleaner additive would be a good idea, or removing and cleaning the injectors but I'd only take that step if I thought I had an actual problem.

As for the motor mounts I personally would recommend replacing them all, if one of them failed then the others are likely to be in the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace the broken motor mount and inspect the others.  It's fair to suggest that if one has failed in operation, it may have put strain on the others and they are all a similar age to the failed one.  However, if it's something like the dog-bone mount, I'd just put a new one on as these are prone to failure.

Chances are that the petrol in the tank may have gone bad in the time it's been standing.  How to proceed very much depends on how much fuel is left in there.  If there is only a small amount, I'd be tempted to brim-fill the fuel tank with fresh fuel and drive it like that.  If there is a reasonable amount in there already I'd personally be tempted to try and start it, I'd even consider adding a splash of octane booster to it.  If it runs terribly or won't start, at that point I'd drain the tank and add fresh fuel.